# Choose $u_{m}\in W_{p}^{2}(\Omega)\cap W_{q}^{2}(\Omega)$ to harmonic function $u$.

Tags: limits, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Let $\Omega$ : bounded, open set and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.
>
> Let $u\in W_{p}^{2}(\Omega)$ satisfy $\triangle u=0$ on $\Omega$.
>
> Then want to choose $u_{m}\in W_{p}^{2}(\Omega)\cap W_{q}^{2}(\Omega)$
>   such that $u_{m}\rightarrow u$ in $W_{p}^{2}(\Omega)$.

If $p<2$, then $W_{p}^{2}\cap W_{q}^{2}=W_{p}^{2}$. So just we can
choose $u_{m}=u$.

If $p\geq2$, $W_{p}^{2}\cap W_{q}^{2} =W_{q}^{2}\subset W_{p}^{2}$. I can't go further here.

Comment: Same question : If $q<p$, $W_{p}^{2}(\Omega)\subset\bar{W_{q}^{2}(\Omega)}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the result in Evans' classical book, we know that if $\Omega$ is of $C^1$, then we can find $u_m\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $u_m\to u$ in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Actually, there is a stronger density result, whose statement is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Sorry the boundary is not in $C^{1}$.

Comment: It is better to point out this. Otherwise, people will think this problem is trivial

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks ice.

Comment: @kayak Then I think this problem is not easy. It may fail to find such approximation.

Comment: is that $C^{\infty}$ a dense subset of $W^{k,p}$ without the smooth boundary condition?

Comment: @kayak Do you have any source of this problem, say you read such statement somewhere.

Comment: @kayak No, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is smooth, but it is not in $H^1((0,\infty))$

Comment: I don't have a book around me now. Ill put the name of the book later. It is called Elliptic problems with nonsmooth boundary condition like this.

Comment: I have this book

Comment: I looked through chapter 4.4.1. The first theorem of the chap 4.4.1. The theorem is showing the dimension of the kernel of laplacian is zero.

Comment: It is Lipschitz domain. Then it is also true

Comment: ahh then the smooth functions are dense in any sobolev spaces?

Comment: @kayak please see my update. Continuous boundary is good enough

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Have a great day.